# Rapid Miner Row Maximum

Tags: max, row, rapidminer

Sorry I'm totally new to RapidMiner and only made the basic tutorial.

I have a dataset like

```
MatchID   Value1   Value2   Value3
1            5        1        2
1           4.5      1.5       2
...
```

and would like to know if there is a possibilty to get the highest value per column (for example Value1) and make further calculations with it (generate attributes).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways as it happens. Here's one using the `Aggregate` operator to find the maxima, `Join` to join this to the original and `Generate Attributes` to do some calculating.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.2.003">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Iris" width="90" x="45" y="34">
    <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="aggregate" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" height="82" name="Aggregate" width="90" x="179" y="34">
    <parameter key="use_default_aggregation" value="true"/>
    <parameter key="default_aggregation_function" value="maximum"/>
    <list key="aggregation_attributes"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="join" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" height="82" name="Join" width="90" x="313" y="34">
    <parameter key="join_type" value="outer"/>
    <parameter key="use_id_attribute_as_key" value="false"/>
    <list key="key_attributes"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="7.2.003" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes" width="90" x="447" y="34">
    <list key="function_descriptions">
      <parameter key="deltaA1" value="[maximum(a1)]-a1"/>
      <parameter key="deltaA2" value="[maximum(a2)]-a2"/>
      <parameter key="deltaA3" value="[maximum(a3)]-a3"/>
      <parameter key="deltaA4" value="[maximum(a4)]-a4"/>
    </list>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Iris" from_port="output" to_op="Aggregate" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Aggregate" from_port="example set output" to_op="Join" to_port="left"/>
      <connect from_op="Aggregate" from_port="original" to_op="Join" to_port="right"/>
      <connect from_op="Join" from_port="join" to_op="Generate Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the `Extract Macro` operator with the `statistics` setting `max`. This stores the maximum for a given attribute as a macro value, which then can be used, e.g. in `Generate Attributes`.

The advantage is that you don't modify the original dataset and don't have to use a `join` or `multiply` operator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.5.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Iris" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="extract_macro" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Extract Macro" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <parameter key="macro" value="maxA1"/>
        <parameter key="macro_type" value="statistics"/>
        <parameter key="statistics" value="max"/>
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="a1"/>
        <list key="additional_macros"/>
        <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">extract maximum of attribute a1 and store it in a macro</description>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes" width="90" x="313" y="34">
        <list key="function_descriptions">
          <parameter key="DifferenceA1" value="parse(%{maxA1})-a1"/>
        </list>
        <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">calculate the difference of a1 from the maximum using the macro value</description>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Iris" from_port="output" to_op="Extract Macro" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Extract Macro" from_port="example set" to_op="Generate Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

*Hint:* since macro values are stored as text, you first have to `parse` them to use their numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

A third option is to `Sort` the example set and only keep the example with the maximum value with a `Filter Example Range` operator. This comes in handy, if you are mostly interested in the values of other attributes, when a certain attribute is maximal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.5.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Iris" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="sort" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Sort" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="a1"/>
        <parameter key="sorting_direction" value="decreasing"/>
        <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">sorting the example set on a1 decreasing</description>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_example_range" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Filter Example Range" width="90" x="313" y="34">
        <parameter key="first_example" value="1"/>
        <parameter key="last_example" value="1"/>
        <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">only keeping the first example, which has the maximum for a1</description>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Iris" from_port="output" to_op="Sort" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Sort" from_port="example set output" to_op="Filter Example Range" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Example Range" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```